# Getting error "Service with id 'jenkins' already exists" while Installing Jenkins as a Windows service

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am facing issue while Installing Jenkins as a Windows service:
Here is the error logs:

```
Error
Installing a service
[.jenkins] $ C:\Users\Lenovo-I7\.jenkins\jenkins.exe install
2019-08-17 15:43:47,662 INFO  - Installing the service with id 'jenkins'
Service with id 'jenkins' already exists
To install the service, delete the existing one or change service Id in the configuration file
2019-08-17 15:43:47,667 FATAL - Unhandled exception
System.Exception: Installation failure: Service with id 'jenkins' already exists
   at winsw.WrapperService.Run(String[] _args, ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
   at winsw.WrapperService.Main(String[] args)
System.Exception: Installation failure: Service with id 'jenkins' already exists
   at winsw.WrapperService.Run(String[] _args, ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
   at winsw.WrapperService.Main(String[] args)
```

I had Jenkins installed in my system before also, I was facing some issues with it, so I uninstalled it and reinstalled it again. And now I am getting this issue.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, there must be some existing service with the name `jenkins`. To remove that, open the command prompt using elevated privilege (i.e., Run as Administrator) and type the command: `sc delete jenkins`

For more details about `sc` command, you may refer [this](https://ss64.com/nt/sc.html) page.

Comment: @RamitDhamija: Thanks for confirming. You may [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer if it helped you.